# Writer behavior when using Partitions in JSR352 Java Batch processing

Tags: jsr352, java-batch

I have implemented a Java batch program using the JSR352 framework implementation available in the Websphere Liberty server container.

This Job is Chunk processing oriented

1. Reader - Read a data
2. Processor - Process it Writer
3. Writer - Write data in a file & update data in another file

***Will the write operation in the Writer over-write each other when i create 2 partitions for this job ? or will both the partitions write output remain in the file without getting overwritten by the other ?***

Comment: Since this is more of a general question, let me give a general answer.  A simple approach is to avoid concurrency issues by parameterizing each partition so that it writes to its own, unique file.   At the end of the step, or at the end of the job, you can combine the various partition outputs into a single output file.      But the developer writes the ItemWriter code and configures the partitions via the partition plan, so it the writer will do whatever you tell it to.    If that doesn't help, please provide more detail on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. I am trying to understand the features of the framework, so that I can guide the design team to make best use of it. Especially, our objective is to build java batch jobs that can run optimized than its COBOL counter parts, so was exploring features which can significantly improve the java job performance. Currently, the team is developing Java batch jobs as simple console applications (to run in z o/s) without any frameworks.